# Arrays of Literals in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

When creating an array of literals in JS:

```
[{ name: 'david', value: 'blue' }, { name: 'harold', value: 'orange' }]
```

The only way I can see of writing this in Coffeescript is:

```
[
  name: 'david'
  value: 'blue'
,
  name: 'harold'
  value: 'orange'
]
```

To me this is pretty ugly, that "floating" comma doesn't really sit well. Are there any alternative syntaxes for this? I am aware you can continue to use a JS-style approach from within Coffeescript but I was hoping for something more concise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been the one thing that every CoffeeScript developer seems to run into.

I'm afraid it's all we have for now. The only other alternative I can think of is:

```
[
  { name: 'david', value: 'blue' }
  { name: 'harold', value: 'orange' }
]
```

… but it's far from ideal itself.

If anyone wanted to suggest an alternate, concise and CS-y syntax, I'd be happy to try to implement it in the parser and make a pull request for it. I'd love to have better than this.

Comment: The only thing that occurred to me was simply:  
  
    [  
      name: 'david', value: 'blue'  <NEWLINE>
      name: 'harold', value: 'orange'  
    ]

Sorry for the poor formatting, this is what I mean:

http://pastebin.com/k0QbUjrv

It would save four more characters and the newline serves as a separator between elements. I suspect there is something else in Coffeescript that prevents this though :)

Comment: @colinramsay: Yeah, that looks good to me too; I'm only reluctant because it already parses as a single option, so it'd break backwards compatibility and be less likely to be accepted.

Comment: @colinramsay The problem with that syntax it that it would be ambiguous as it conflicts with the object literal syntax ([example](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#try:obj%20%3D%20%0A%20%20one%3A%201%2C%20two%3A%202%0A%20%20three%3A%203%2C%20four%3A%204): an object literal taking more than one line and with more than one property per line), and objects cannot have repeated keys.

Comment: As a new syntax addition, i would prefer [LiveScript](http://gkz.github.com/LiveScript/)'s use of asterisks to denote object literals inside arrays :)

Comment: @epidemian the asterisk approach is ok I guess, I wonder if it'd be accepted?

Comment: @colinramsay: personally, I'd prefer to fix up the existing behaviour of commas in object literals. ([i.e. this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%5B%0A%20%20a%3A%20b%0A%2C%20c%3A%20d%0A%2C%20e%3A%20f%0A%20%20g%3A%20h%0A%20%20i%3A%20j%0A%5D%0A%0A%23%23%23%0A%20%20Should%20become%20%5B%7B%20a%3A%20b%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20c%3A%20d%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20e%3A%20f%2C%20g%3A%20h%2C%20i%3A%20j%20%7D%5D.%0A%20%20Not%20this%20monstrosity.%0A%23%23%23))

Comment: @Len The problem with that syntax is not only that it produces something unexpected, but it's also very fragile ([e.g.](http://coffeescript.org/#try:[%0A%20%20a%3A%20b%0A%2C%20c%3A%20d%0A%20%20x%3A%20y%0A%2C%20e%3A%20f%0A%20%20g%3A%20h%0A%20%20i%3A%20j%0A]%0A%0A%23%23%23%0A%20%20By%20the%20same%20logic%2C%20this%20should%20become%0A%20%20[{a%3Ab}%2C%20{c%3Ad%2C%20x%3Ay}%2C%20{e%3Af%2C%20g%3Ah%2C%20i%3Aj}].%0A%20%20But%20it%20breaks.%0A%23%23%23))... (it's also quite ugly IMO). Adding a newline after each comma fixes that ([minified link 'cause i run out of characters xD](http://goo.gl/ehd7j)).

Answer (score 14):

I can't remember why this works, or even if it's useful to you, but it's another alternative to the code you're writing.

```
[
  {}= name: 'david', value: 'blue'
  {}= name: 'harold', value: 'orange'
]
```

[Yes, this seems to work.](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%5B%0A%20%20%7B%7D=%20name:%20%27david%27,%20value:%20%27blue%27%0A%20%20%7B%7D=%20name:%20%27harold%27,%20value:%20%27orange%27%0A%5D)

This also weirdly seems to work. I'm sure there's a simple reason for it, but I'm not sure of it.

```
[
  {}= 
    name: 'david'
    value: 'blue'
  {}= 
    name: 'harold'
    value: 'orange'
  {}= 
    name: 'david'
    value: 'blue'
]
```

[See the compiled code.](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%5B%0A%20%20%7B%7D=%20%0A%20%20%20%20name:%20%27david%27%0A%20%20%20%20value:%20%27blue%27%0A%20%20%7B%7D=%20%0A%20%20%20%20name:%20%27harold%27%0A%20%20%20%20value:%20%27orange%27%0A%20%20%7B%7D=%20%0A%20%20%20%20name:%20%27david%27%0A%20%20%20%20value:%20%27blue%27%0A%5D)

Comment: o_O This is really weird. Me likes! =D

Comment: `{} =` is an empty destructuring assignment which destructs nothing and simply evaluates to the right operand. `[] =` works the same as well.

Answer (score 8):

To get rid of the commas inside the object literals you can go for:

```
[
  {
    name: 'david'
    value: 'blue'
  }, {
    name: 'harold'
    value: 'orange'
  }, {
    name: 'david'
    value: 'blue'
  }
]
```

Or, if you *really* hate commas:

```
[
  {
    name: 'david'
    value: 'blue'
  }
  {
    name: 'harold'
    value: 'orange'
  }
  {
    name: 'david'
    value: 'blue'
  }
]
```

Though i personally feel that the floating commas, indented one level, don't look so bad:

```
[
    name: 'david'
    value: 'blue'
  , 
    name: 'harold'
    value: 'orange'
  , 
    name: 'david'
    value: 'blue'
]
```

I think it makes it pretty obvious when object literals start and finish and it also makes it nearly impossible to forget a comma between object literals =D

Answer (score 0):

@Yuki Izumi asks how this should be implemented (I don't have the karma to comment on his reply directly).

What I childishly attempt to do in coffeescript is something like this:

```
arrayOfLiterals =
  'somekey': 'someval'
  'otherkey': 'otherval'
     'keyInOtherArrayElement': 'andItsVal'
     'yetMoreInSecondElement': 'andItsVal'
  'thirdElement': 'val'
     'fourthElement': 'val'
```

This is my two cents